# insertion sort last item undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, insertion-sort

I am practicing hackerrank and want to process a data structure using insertion sort. Given the type String data structure:

```
6
1 4 3 5 6 2
```

I want to count from index starting at value 1, so counting index 0 the array's size, and new line character, I should start at 2. I want to at every loop log the output of each step of shifting the array index left or right.

```
function processData(input) {     
    function sort(input) {
        let values = input.split('\n')
        values = values[1].split(' ').map(i => parseInt(i));        
        var length = values.length;
        for(var i = 1; i < length; i++) {          

            console.log('input sort', values[i])
            var temp = values[i] === undefined ? null: values[i];
            var j = i - 1;
            for(j; j >= 0 && values[j] > temp; --j) {
                values[j+1] = values[j];    
            }
            values[j+1] = temp;
            var result = values.join(" ");

            console.log(values);
       }
       // return values;
   };
};
```

my output is below. Notice the trailing undefined. I'm still new to these sorting algorithms and I'm hoping someone can explain where that is coming from.

```
input sort 4
[ 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 3
[ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 5
[ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 6
[ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 2
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
undefined
```

I would like an output without the undefined character.

```
[ 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 3
[ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 5
[ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 6
[ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 ]
input sort 2
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This has nothing to do with your algorithm.

You see that part at the very end that looks like:

```
   // return values;
```

Delete the `//`.

You are getting `undefined` on the last line because the function has no return value and you are running it in a console.  It's not coming from one of your `console.log` statements, but from the default console behavior of printing out the result of the last line that executed.  In this case, that last line is a function with no value that yields `undefined`.